# S(x+iy)= (ax+by)+i(cx+dy)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T\colon C\to C$  be a linear transformation such that
$$T\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$$ 
Define
$$S(x+iy)= (ax+by)+i(cx+dy)$$
Then is $S$ a linear transformation for all $a, b, c, d\in C$? It is a L.T. if $a = d$ and $b=-c$, but doubtful for arbitrary $a, b, c, d$. Please give your precious suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Please fix the peculiar thing after "such that" -- I can't read it.

Comment: After asking over ten questions, please learn how to format your question using LaTeX/MathJax markup.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\mathbb{C}$ can be viewed as a vector space over various fields $\mathbb{F}$. So the answer really depends on $\mathbb{F}$.

By definition, $S$ is linear if $S(\alpha z_1 + z_2)=\alpha S(z_1)+S(z_2)$ for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}$ and $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$. When $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ (so that $\mathbb{C}$ is a two-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ with basis $\{1,i\}$), you may verify that $S$ is linear.

If $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ (so that $\mathbb{C}$ one-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ with basis $\{1\}$) and the $a,b,c,d$ in your definition of $S$ are real numbers, then as you said, $S$ is linear iff $a=d$ and $b=-c$. However, if $a,b,c,d$ --- as you have stated in your question --- are *complex* numbers, then the necessary and sufficient condition for $S$ to be linear is $b+c=i(a-d)$.

Comment: Why in particular if $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{C}$ should $b+c=i(a-d)$? Rather how did you figure it out? I tried it with an example and indeed it is true. But I wanted to know how to prove it in general.

Comment: @YadatiKiran I supposed the domain and codomain of $S$ are both $\mathbb C$ (so that $x$ and $y$ are complex numbers). The OP asked when is $S$ a linear transformation. Actually, as long as $S$ is well defined, it is always linear. However, the subtle point is that $S$ needs to be well defined first. That is, if $x+iy=X+iY$ for some $x,y,X,Y\in\mathbb C$, we need $S(x+iy)=S(X+iY)$. The premise $x+iy=X+iY$ means that $x-X=i(Y-y)$. Hence the condition $S(x+iy)=S(X+iY)$ implies that $(a+ic)(x-X)=(b+id)(Y-y)$ and in turn $(a+ic)i=(b+id)$, i.e. $b+c=i(a-d)$.

Comment: I was stuck at $(a+ic)(x-X)=(b+id)(Y-y)$. Now I understand. Thank you.